# How to implement an event if I have event in interface, also how I can use it in dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I have created a separate class to handle mail sending. To make it hassle free from future changes I have used dependency injection to design it. Now, when I try to use `SendMessageAsync()` method, I want to check SendMailCompleted event to see status of message sent failed/succeeded. I am confused how I'm supposed to implement the event in the class that is implementing it. Without mentioning this event in the interface I won't be able to catch it in the injection class. Can any one suggest how to solve this? My interface looks like as follows

```
public interface IMailing
{
    string Host { get; set; }
    int Port { get; set; }
    Task SendMailAsync(string toAddress, string subject, string body);

    event SendCompletedEventHandler OnEmailSendComplete;
}
```

The class that is implementing the interface is as follows -

```
public class Mailing : IMailing
{
    private SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mm = null;

    public string Host{ get;  set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }

// do i need this? without event being in the interface I would have had this //two following lines to manually raise the event 
    public event SendCompletedEventHandler OnEmailSendComplete;

    public delegate void SendCompletedEventHandler(object source, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e);



// following lines were generated from the vs2017 IDE
// how do I use it when actual Send mail completed event fires?
    event System.Net.Mail.SendCompletedEventHandler IMailing.OnEmailSendComplete
    {
        add
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        remove
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public async Task SendMailAsync(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {            
        mm = new MailMessage(User, toAddress, subject, body);
        client.SendCompleted += Client_SendCompleted;
        await client.SendMailAsync(mm).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void Client_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnEmailSendComplete?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Now, the injection class uses constructor injection, which looks like follows -

```
public class MailingInjection
{
    IMailing mailing = null;

    private MailingInjection()
    { }
    public MailingInjection(IMailing imail)
    {
        mailing = imail;
    }              

    public async Task SenMailAsync(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        mailing.OnEmailSendComplete += EmailSendCompleted;
        await mailing.SendMailAsync(to, subject,body).ConfigureAwait(false);   
    }

    private void EmailSendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        mailing.OnEmailSendComplete -= EmailSendCompleted;
    }
}
```

I tried to put as less code as possible to explain my confusion so this code will not work in real scenarios but has the structure I believe. Please let me know if I have over exaggerated it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by *I am confused how I'm supposed to implement the event in the class that is implementing it. Without mentioning this event in the interface I won't be able to catch it in the injection class* are saying you dont want the implementation to manage the event?

Comment: I do want to manage it; in the implementation, the part where it says "not implemented" how I place my  delegate event to raise so I can catch in the injected class.

Comment: You implement the event in the interface the same way you'd implement any event. Based on the code you posted, it appears you used the "Implement interface explicitly" option in Visual Studio, which gives you (surprise!) the explicit form of an event declaration, with the `add()` and `remove()` methods. If you don't want special handling for the event, then don't do that. Just declare the event as in the interface, i.e. `public event SendCompletedEventHandler OnEmailSendComplete;` and let the compiler fill in the `add()` and `remove()` methods for you.

Comment: I just dont get it why people down vote, It takes a lot to earn reputation to ask/post something here in stackoverflow. If I have known what I'm trying to do I wouldn't have come here...people need to understand this fact.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is conflating two different asynchronous patterns: the older [event-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap) and the new [task-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap). In particular, `SmtpClient.SendCompleted` is only used with `SmtpClient.SendAsync`. Your code isn't using `SendAsync`, so it doesn't need `SendCompleted`. It can just use `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync` instead:

```
public interface IMailing
{
  string Host { get; set; }
  int Port { get; set; }
  Task SendMailAsync(string toAddress, string subject, string body);
  // No event necessary.
}

public class Mailing : IMailing
{
  private SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  MailMessage mm = null;

  public string Host{ get;  set; }
  public int Port { get; set; }

  public async Task SendMailAsync(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
  {            
    mm = new MailMessage(User, toAddress, subject, body);
    await client.SendMailAsync(mm).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MailingInjection
{
  ...

  public async Task SenMailAsync(string to, string subject, string body)
  {
    await mailing.SendMailAsync(to, subject,body).ConfigureAwait(false);   
  }
}
```

As a final reminder, if your abstraction has only one implementation, it's not an abstraction. ;)

Comment: Actually I have more in it, just didn't wanted to flood it with tons of code, so just posted the part where I have doubt. I confused SendAsync() with SendMailAsync(). But I need to know these two patterns you mentioned +1.